# URI errors when loading certain types of translated files into the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the model derivative uploader to prepare files for viewing and then passing the urn of the translated file to the viewer tutorial via an ajax request.

I am getting an error when attempting to view certain types of translated files.

Translated .step files work well and the models load with no errors. However,  .stl, .rvt and .dwx files throw errors when initialising the viewer. I tried even with some sample models provided on the github page and the errors still persist.

when trying to view an STL model i get this error:

[image: error in chrome console]

when trying to view a 3DM model I get this error:

[image: error in chrome console]

The errors seems to relate to the URL used to make the request to fetch the model. I am not sure what is causing these errors as I am only changing the urn value.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first guess would be that you are passing incorrect URNs. Can you show how your URNs look like? Also do you have a sample stl or 3dm file you can share? You can give a try to upload a model on my sample at https://oss.autodesk.io

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeLeefsma 

This file uploads and translates the model as described in the model derivative tutorial, when the conversion finishes it saves the urn as a json file:
https://github.com/hrryndrsn/forge-upload-and-view/blob/master/forge.js

The urn is saved as a json file here:
https://github.com/hrryndrsn/forge-upload-and-view/blob/master/savedUrn.json

The urn recalled using an ajax request in my viewer js here:
https://github.com/hrryndrsn/forge-upload-and-view/blob/master/www/js/viewer.js

Comment: Here is a model that gives an error when uploading:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9iot0rsbhz330y6/test-model.stl?dl=0

i tried uploading it to your sample at oss.autodesk.io but when i click 'get viewable' it just says 'there is no derivative'

thanks for your help

Comment: Works fine so you must be doing something wrong, take a look at the recording below that shows the steps for the oss demo: select a bucket, upload the file, right-click the file-> generate viewable, double-click item to load in viewer. https://screencast.com/t/jftFVaLMz9. I will take a look at your code to see if I can easily spot the mistake. In the meantime feel free to browse our github repo where you can find numerous examples: https://github.com/autodesk-forge

Comment: I can't tell what is the problem but the project you are using looks like a messy one. Take a look at the projects in my repo: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs. Try first project #5 which is the same than the one deployed at https://oss.autodesk.io. You will start on a much cleaner basis. By the way your Forge credentials are now compromised as you placed them in clear text in the project you uploaded. If you pay for using Forge, it is probably not a good idea to share those publicly. You can regenerate a private key from your account and use ENV variables instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help @PhilippeLeefsma I will follow your advice.